# Error if direct URL of react-router with params is passed to browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**FILES** 
https://github.com/microcyberz/expensify

When I access this URL `http://localhost:8081/edit/01` with built-in navigation of react-router, it works fine. Route is `<Route path="/edit/:id/" component={EditExpensePage} />`.

But when I put the same URL directly in the browser, I get following two lines of error in console and page doesn't render anything.

Errors

```
GET http://localhost:8081/edit/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
GET http://localhost:8081/edit/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I will be thankful for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem:

https://github.com/microcyberz/expensify/blob/master/public/index.html#L13

You're loading the bundle.js relative to the current path, in stead of absolute from the root. Change this to /bundle.js and you're good to go.

In your example, the js is loaded relative to the current url, resolving from `/edit/123` to `/edit/bundle.js`

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I am unable to upvote this answer due to limited experience but I will do it as soon as I become eligible. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because your server is not redirecting to the index file. I mean what's behind http://localhost:8081? Is it node? Are you sure that every single request is handled the same way?

Also you may check how you include your `bundle.js`. Is the path relative like `./assets/js/bundle.js` or absolute like `/assets/js/bundle.js`? Should be absolute.

Comment: In this particular case, most probably, the index is loaded, but the reference to bundle.js is not absolute (i.e. is loaded relative to the current page, e.g. "bundle.js" or "../js/bundle.js" in stead of "/js/bundle.js") Otherwise, the JS wouldn't be the 404, the page shown would.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is resolved by adding "/" before bundle.js in index.html.

Comment: @krasimir Thanks man I was frustrated because of this error, I spent a lot of time but never got the solution, Now I came to this problem and read your answer, I was using a relative path in `index.html` and I changed it to an absolute path and that worked for me. Thanks a lot man...

Answer (score 1):

This problem will also appear when using webpack and the HtmlWebpackPlugin. It can be solved by using the `publicPath` config option, which will prepend each script tag with a `/`:

```js
//webpack.config.js
{
...
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWepbackPlugin({
      ...
      publicPath: '/'
    })
  ]
}
```